# Saxon HE 9.7 XQuery results and existing document

Tags: xquery, saxon

I am new to Saxon.

In my java application, I have a requirement that I need to XQuery an existing dom4j document. The XQuery is to order few elements in an descending order by serialNo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataOfBooks:DataOfBooks xmlns:dataOfBooks="DataOfBooks">
  <Id>ID123</Id>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>ccc</name>
      <serialNo>77</serialNo>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>aaa</name>
      <serialNo>99</serialNo>
    </book>
  </books>
</dataOfBooks:DataOfBooks>
```

Once I get the XQuery results, I need to add those back to the above existing document. I tried using net.sf.saxon.s9api. I was able to get the XQuery results back as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result:sequence
  xmlns:result="http://saxon.sf.net/xquery-results"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <result:element>
    <book xmlns:data="dataOfBooks">
      <name>aaa</name>
      <serialNo>99</serialNo>
    </book>
    <book xmlns:data="dataOfBooks">
      <name>aaa</name>
      <serialNo>77</serialNo>
    </book>
  </result:element>
</result:sequence>
```

But I have two issues. 1) the result has namespaces and extra stuff that I do not want. 2) It is not very clear to me as which Saxon API to use to add the XQuery results to the existing document. So that the resultant document looks as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataOfBooks:DataOfBooks xmlns:dataOfBooks="DataOfBooks">
  <Id>ID123</Id>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>aaa</name>
      <serialNo>99</serialNo>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>ccc</name>
      <serialNo>77</serialNo>
    </book>
  </books>
</dataOfBooks:DataOfBooks>
```

One more question - I tried using dynamicContext and treeinfo classes since I though the usage of treeinfo API might be more optimal, but no luck. If you think, usage of TreeInfo API is efficient, I really appreciate a code example for my requirement. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time and interest.

Comment: If you supply details of your query, we can tell you where you have gone wrong, and if you supply details of your Java code, then we can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your XQuery code is producing unwanted namespaces is because your query is wrong, but we can't tell you how it is wrong unless you show us the code.

The `result:sequence` in your output suggests that you have somehow contrived to ask for output in "wrapped" format, which suggests some kind of misuse of Saxon APIs. Again, without seeing your code, we can't tell you exactly what you have done wrong.

To make small changes to an existing document, leaving the rest unchanged, I would normally recommend XSLT over XQuery. In XSLT 3.0, you can sort the books by name using the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="books">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:perform-sort select="book">
      <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

In both XQuery and XSLT, the result of your query/transformation is a new document, which you can use in place of the original. If you want to make in-situ updates to an existing document, you can do this using XQuery Update; however Saxon does not support XQuery Update against documents in DOM4J format.

Saxon does allow you to capture the result of a query or transformation as a DOM4J Document, and you could use DOM4J APIs to graft this document (or rather, its outermost element) back into the original DOM4J document.

**Later**

You have now provided your code (you should have provided it as an edit to the original question, not as an answer).

I guess your DOMWriter is the DOM4J class of that name, which like much of DOM4J is rather badly documented. But I think it is copying the DOM4J tree to a DOM tree, which you definitely don't want to do. If you really want to copy the tree to make it convenient for Saxon, you should copy it to a Saxon tree, but for this use case it's best to leave it in DOM4J form. Use

```
DocumentBuilder builder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode inDoc = builder.wrap(dom4jdoc);
```

When you run your query, the resulting XdmValue will now be a sequence of XdmNode objects, each of which is a wrapper around a DOM4J Element node. These element nodes are still attached to the original DOM4J tree, and they still have their original namespaces. There is no need to serialize the result to lexical XML.

You can copy the result to a List value by writing

```
List<Element> sortedNodes = new ArrayList<Element>();
for (XdmItem item : result) {
   sortedNodes.add(((Element)((XdmNode)item).getExternalNode()));
}
```

and then (if I read the DOM4J documentation correctly) you can replace the content of the containing `books` element with

```
Element books = (Element)sortedNodes.get(0).getParent();
List booksContent = books.elements();
booksContent.clear();
booksContent.addAll(sortedBooks);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, Just a FYI - I provided my code as an answer to this post. I still have issues with updating the existing document. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Since I am using Saxon HE 9.7.x, I am getting exception while builder.wrap(dom4j document). I tried registering registerExternalObjectModel with configuration but in vain as it is not supported in HE. Our company wants us to stay with HE edition. I really hope there is an alternative way to accomplish my xquery requirement.

Comment: We were successfully able to use HE 9.5.x version for our requirement using the dynamicContext/documentwrapper approach - it fails in HE 9.7.x version.

Comment: This fails in 9.7.x  - dynamicContext.setContextItem(new DocumentWrapper(doc, BASE_URI, configuration)). Since Documentwrapper no longer is of ITEM type in 9.7.x.

Comment: If you stick to s9api classes and methods you will have far less problem with compatibility between releases. That's why I suggested the correct way to create the wrapper is with `DocumentBuilder.wrap()`.

Comment: If you want to work directly with DOM4J in Saxon then you will need Saxon-PE or higher (§). If you have to find a Saxon-HE solution, then you're not going to be able to use this approach which combines Saxon and DOM4J processing to produce the result. I would suggest you then go back to the approach of transforming the whole document using XSLT, as I first suggested, and then converting the result back to DOM4J. (§ Caveat: that's not strictly true: the source code of the DOM4J support package is available, and you could integrate it yourself if you want to save the £60 cost of a PE license).